# Randomly truncated WebSocket message even under 125 bytes

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, chromium

I am trying to send a message to a WebSockets server written in C++.

This is the script I am using to send data in the browser console:

```
function quickTest(wsURL, service) {
    var w = new WebSocket(wsURL);

    w.onopen = function () {
        console.debug('Identifying as', service);
        w.send(service);
    }

    w.onmessage = function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.data);
    }

    w.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.error(evt.data);
    }

    w.onclose = function () {
        console.debug('Goodbye.');
    }

    return w;
}

var x = quickTest('ws://some-uri:9000', 'keyword');
x.send('i lost my phone');
```

I just initialise a `quickTest` and repeatedly call the send function to see what happens. Most of the time, the server receives the text message correctly:

```
i lost my phone
```

and sometimes, it is divided into two (one such example from Chromium):

```
i lost my ph
Hï¿½`
```

or completely garbled (example from Firefox):

```
L\u0002T\u001C\u0007\u001C\u001A\t
```

Is there a particular reason for this to happen at random? It occurs with Chromium 32 and Firefox 27.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You should get 21 bytes in the server, 2 for header, 4 for key and 15 for content. Can you check what are you getting when it fails?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check as soon as I can. The logs right now are incomplete, I'll write a server soon and see what is happening.

Comment: It seems to have been the server struggling after all. The guy who wrote the original server has patched it and that problem no longer occurs... but I hope I can still do some legwork on this issue